# Rails HABTM query where condition is based on association attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have User and Album models with HABTM relationship

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many(:albums)
```

I'd like to find all the albums that are stored in the database but not associated with a particular user.

So far my code is like this:

`Album.all(:order => "albums.created_at DESC", :include => "users", :limit => limit, :conditions => ["users.id != ? AND users.id IS NOT NULL", current_user.id])`

but for some reason this is not working. It's returning albums that are associated with current_user.

here take a look at this ouptput from the console. 
Check the users id i first fetch.
Then i fetch albums which should not have the users id
I then find one of the listed albums and ask it to return the associated users
one of those associated users is the one from above and shouldnt be there.
[image]

Can anyone help with the above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually try to stay away sub-selects but I can't seem to get it to work any other way:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :without_user, lambda{|u| where("#{quoted_table_name}.id NOT IN (SELECT `albums_users`.album_id FROM `albums_users` WHERE `albums_users`.user_id = ?)", u.id) }

end

user = User.find(30)
Album.without_user(user)
```

Comment: @robodisco: doesn't this work for you? Is something unclear here? Imho this is the best answer.

Comment: sorry for late reply - im living in japan and the recent earthquake and radiation fears have been a bit disruptive. Thanks for you help. Ive marked yours as the choosen answer - i assume the bounty is then yours though im sure i specified 50 and not the 25 that is showing up.

Comment: also what does quoted_table_name refer to?

Comment: `quoted_table_name` wraps the class' table name declaration with quotes. Some db's don't always like just having `album.column`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you created table albums_users to hold relationship data:

```
Album.includes(:users).  
    where(["albums_users.user_id IS NULL OR albums_users.user_id != ?", user_id])
```

I think it will generate SQL along the lines of

```
SELECT *
FROM albums LEFT OUTER JOIN albums_users ON albums.id = albums_users.album_id
WHERE albums_users.album_id IS NULL OR albums_users.album_id != #{user_id}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
:conditions => ["users.id <> ? AND users.id IS NOT NULL", current_user.id]
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately no luck, this doesn't change the results. Its still returns some albums that when i check for their associated users, the current_user turns up.

Answer (score -1):

A non-sql solution would be:

```
Album.all.reject{|album| user.albums.include?(album)}
```

Obviously, if you have tens of thousands of rows in your database, you might not want to do this.

Might do something like this, too:

```
Album.where(["id NOT IN (?)", user.albums_ids])
```

But if your users have a lot (say hundreds) of albums, you shouldn't do this either.

Just throwing in easy solutions if you're out for one of those.

Comment: yeah they're nice easy solutions and I would go for them for v1 but as you said there not great when there are lots of rows and thats true in my case.